# how to set permissions to cache and log symfony docker container

Tags: php, symfony, docker, nginx

I have a `Dockerfile` for my Symfony application but the container doesn't have write permissions into the cache and logs directories.

I tried with the Symfony docs for permissions, but it is not working. I already set the container user to root, but the problem is the same.

Here is my `Dockerfile`:

```sh
FROM trafex/alpine-nginx-php7:ba1dd422

RUN apk --update add git php7-sockets php7-bcmath php7-pdo_mysql php7-pdo && rm /var/cache/apk/* \
    && curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

COPY ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

COPY . /var/www/html

RUN composer install \
     --ignore-platform-reqs \
        --no-interaction \
        --no-plugins \
        --no-scripts \
        --prefer-dist

EXPOSE 8080
```

How can I set the correct permissions to run it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/TrafeX/docker-php-nginx/blob/acf639ead25710d1448873fcfcb2027070707607/Dockerfile#L30) of the docker image it seems like the user running both NGINX and PHP-FPM is `nobody`.

So you should be able to make it all work giving this user the rights on those files

```sh
FROM trafex/alpine-nginx-php7:ba1dd422

RUN apk --update add git php7-sockets php7-bcmath php7-pdo_mysql php7-pdo && rm /var/cache/apk/* \
    && curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

COPY ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

COPY . /var/www/html
RUN chown -R nobody:nobody /var/www/html

RUN composer install \
     --ignore-platform-reqs \
        --no-interaction \
        --no-plugins \
        --no-scripts \
        --prefer-dist

EXPOSE 8080
```

**But better yet**, you should use the same syntax as [they use in the original image](https://github.com/TrafeX/docker-php-nginx/blob/acf639ead25710d1448873fcfcb2027070707607/Dockerfile#L34)

```sh
FROM trafex/alpine-nginx-php7:ba1dd422

RUN apk --update add git php7-sockets php7-bcmath php7-pdo_mysql php7-pdo && rm /var/cache/apk/* \
    && curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

COPY ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

COPY --chown=nobody . /var/www/html

RUN composer install \
     --ignore-platform-reqs \
        --no-interaction \
        --no-plugins \
        --no-scripts \
        --prefer-dist

EXPOSE 8080
```